# Why is my :leave-Animation not working although the :enter-animation works?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular-ng-if

In my home.component.html: If I click on the icon, the function `activateProfileSidebar` sets the boolean `showProfileSidebar` to true.

```
<i class="fas fa-user-circle user-icon" *ngIf="user" (click)="activateProfileSidebar()"> {{user.username}} </i>

<app-profile-navbar *ngIf="showProfileSidebar"></app-profile-navbar>
```

and home.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedSrv.getShowProfileSidebar().subscribe(value => this.showProfileSidebar = value);
}
activateProfileSidebar(){
   this.sharedSrv.setShowProfileSidebar(true);
}
```

The :enter-Animation works fine
and in my profile-navbar.component.html, you can close the profile-sidebar.

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper" [@fade]>
     <i class="fas fa-times" (click)="closeProfileSidebar()"></i>
</nav>
```

the profile-navbar.ts file

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition(':enter', [
          style({'width': '0' }),
          animate(200, style({'width': '260px'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
          animate(200, style({'width': '0px'}))
      ])

  ])
  ]
})

...

closeProfileSidebar(){
    this.sharedSrv.setShowProfileSidebar(false);
}
```

Strangely, only the :enter-Animation works but if I close the profile-sidebar again the :leave-Animation does not work.

Comment: the animation and the *ngIf should be in the same tag, e.g. `<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper" [@fade] *ngIf="yourcondition">`

Comment: @Eliseo Hey, thanks for the information. I will try it and change the setup!

Comment: You were right, I did change the setup and did as you say and now the leave-Animation alsoworks. Thanks!